# How can I trigger a wrestling move against the rank 6 boss in No More Heroes?

Tags: no-more-heroes

I'm stuck on Holly Summers (on Mild difficulty). After several failures, I quit the mission and went and searched the city for money and Lovikov balls to upgrade my katana and learn all the wrestling moves. When I started the rank 6 mission again, nearly every enemy I hit was stunned, and I killed 90% of them with wrestling moves. I don't know if this was because of the new katana or a Lovikov technique, but it made things a lot easier.

I'm not getting wrestling moves off against Holly any more often, though, and I don't notice a pattern. Is there a way to consistently stun her so I can perform them?

Comment: Thanks for adding the game title tag! I didn't have enough rep to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall using primarily charge kicks against her (and most other bosses, if I wanted to grapple them). Avoid her attacks until there's an opening (like right after she throws something), then hold B (on the Wii remote; I don't know the new controls) to do a charged kick. This should stun her and let you get a wrestling move in. You can use the katana as a lead-in if you want, but the kick is the important part. Make sure you're in the correct high vs. low stance as well.

If you're having trouble with the holes, swinging the beam katana will reveal them *before* you fall in.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I played NMH, and I know that the first time I met Holly I had a tough time. I seem to recall that the main thing to do is keep moving (avoiding the hole traps and evading her missiles) and, when you get close to her (move fast!) hit her with your katana a couple of times them try kicking/grappling her (with B).